# Wie nennt man die grammatische Konstruktion "Digitalisierungsbefürworter und -gegner"?

Tags: technical-terminology, terminology

Ich finde nicht heraus, ob es einen Terminus Technicus für die grammatische Konstruktion gibt, in der ein zweimal verwendeter Wortteil durch einen Bindestrich ersetzt bzw. in gesprochener Sprache einfach weggelassen wird. Anderes Beispiel: Lang- und Kurzstreckenflüge.

ChatGPT hat mir schon "Bindestrich-Suffix" vorgeschlagen, was nicht stimmen kann, weil die Konstruktion auch in gesprochener Sprache üblich ist.

Comment: Vor allem ist da kein Suffix. Vergiss den Bot.

Comment: Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob das eine grammatische Konstruktion ist, oder doch eher eine typographische. Stichwort [Ergänzungs(binde)strich](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viertelgeviertstrich#Erg%C3%A4nzungsstrich) bzw. [Auslassungszeichen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Auslassungszeichen)

Answer (score 3):

Allenfalls "Koordination von Wortteilen" (Imo: Grammatik. Eine Einführung, Metzler, Stuttgart 2016, S. 104).

Answer (score 3):

In meinem Buch »DUDEN Richtiges und gutes Deutsch (1998)« werden unter dem Stichwort **Ellipse (Ersparung von Redeteilen)** 11 Arten genannt. Auszug:

> *7. Feld- und Gartenfrüchte · auf- und abladen · Wahr- oder Falschheit · en- und proklitisch:*  Haben aufeinander folgende Zusammensetzungen
> das Grundwort oder das Bestimmungswort gemeinsam, so wird dieses
> gewöhnlich nur einmal genannt:
> Feld- und Gartenfrüchte, Ein- und Ausgang, Waren auf- und abladen, Lederherstellung und -vertrieb, Bundeswirtschafts- und Finanzminister,
> Textilgroß- und -einzelhandel.

Answer (score 1):

Für den schriftlichen Aspekt gibt es wenig Spielraum, der heißt [Ergänzungsstrich](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6209). Ich stimme zu, dass das für Gesprochenes nicht so recht passt, habe aber auch keinen anderen Begriff für Wort(-teil)-auslassung gefunden. Ich hege allerdings den Verdacht, dass man das dort ohnehin anders lösen würde:

- entweder man lässt gar nichts weg (reden geht schneller als tippen)
- oder man formuliert um, was mir auch für die Schriftform empfehlenswert erscheint: *Gegner und Befürworter der Digitalisierung*.

Comment: Fun fact: Es gibt Menschen, die sehr viel schneller tippen können als normale Menschen reden - Der Tipprekord liegt bei ca 500 Zeichen/Minute, normales Sprechen sind ca. 90-100  Wörter/Minute. Nimmt man kurze Wörter an, kommt man durchaus in Bereiche, wo das Tippen schneller ist als das Sprechen

Comment: Nein, das kommt im gesprochenen Deutsch definitv vor … Vor- und Nachteile gegeneinander abwägen, die Zu- und Abflüsse, usw. würde ich mündlich allesamt weder umformulieren noch *nicht* verwenden.